# Grep code explanation

Tags: command-line, grep

In a file `weather.xml`, there is the string `temp="103"`.
I run this command

```
grep -o "temp=\"[^\"]*\"" ~/.cache/weather.xml
```

The output is `103`.

What does `[^\"]` mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regular expressions, `[...]` indicates a range of characters to match, and (in that context) `^` indicates negation. So `[^\"]` means any character except literal double quote. So `"[^"]*"` means a double quote, followed by a sequence of zero or more characters except double quote, followed by the closing double quote.

Note that the backslash escapes are only required because you've used double quotes around the expression - you could simplify that to

```
grep -o 'temp="[^"]*"' ~/.cache/weather.xml
```

If you want it to output just the numeric temperature reading, you can use a Perl-compatible RE instead

```
grep -Po 'temp="\K[^"]*'
```

Answer (score 1):

this means - skip an occurrence of double quote.

> > grep -o -> Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.
> >
> > * -> this means 0 or more, hence getting 103
> >
> > \" -> the last double quote in temp="103"

Comment: How does he got 103 , where temp=" , and the last "

Comment: grep -o -> Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
              with each such part on a separate output line.